# Sorting numeric strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting

I've got an array of string version numbers which I'd like to sort but can't for the life of me get them to sort the way I want:

```
versions = [ "1.0.4", "1.0.6", "1.0.11", "1.1.9", "1.1.10", "1.0.16" ]

versions.sort_by {|v| [v.size]}
=> ["1.0.4", "1.0.6", "1.1.9", "1.0.11", "1.1.10", "1.0.16"]
```

Trying to achieve:

```
=> ["1.0.4", "1.0.6", "1.0.11", "1.0.16", "1.1.9", "1.1.10"]
```

It seems to have something to do with lexicographically but I'm having difficulty working out the sorting rule I need to apply.

Any help or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Break it apart into individual numbers and sort by each. Or use multiplication and do 1st * 1000, 2nd * 100, etc. and add 'em up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
versions = [ "1.0.4", "1.0.6", "1.0.11", "1.1.9", "1.1.10", "1.0.16" ]
sorted = versions.sort_by {|s| s.split('.').map(&:to_i) }
sorted # => ["1.0.4", "1.0.6", "1.0.11", "1.0.16", "1.1.9", "1.1.10"]
```

What this does is it splits strings into components and compares them numerically.

Comment: @Stefan: thanks for fixing the output. Messed that up a little bit while editing :)